# Change text to display image

Tags: html, css

I have this line of code which reads '<'. It acts as a navigation button for some of my pages. I want to be able to show an image here instead, however I'm struggling to do so. I've tried background-image and so forth. Here's the code:

```
 {% if paginate.previous %}
{{ '<' | link_to: paginate.previous.url }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This is neither HTML nor CSS, is it.

Comment: Well whatever it is, I have come here because I am unclear. Get off your high horse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If HTML code is supported, you can use this:

```
{{ '<img src="back.png" />' | link_to: paginate.previous.url }}
```

or this:

```
{{ '<span class="back">&lt;</span>' | link_to: paginate.previous.url }}
```

and add CSS:

```
.back { background-image: url(back.png); }
```

When this will work, we can tune-up the style for correct appearance.

Comment: Cheers Vrata! I've been struggling with that for a while. All sorted now :)